# Unable to re-position html button inside media query

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move my `button` towards the left as it's inclined more to the right when I view it in an ipad. This is my **html** code:

```css
#save{
     border-radius: 12px;
     padding-left: 20px;
     padding-right: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    #save{
        /*float: left;*/
        margin-left: 20em;
        /*position: absolute;
        left: 20em;*/
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="save" style="font-size: 20px; position: absolute; left: 39em; top:31.5em;">Save</button>
```

Nothing works, the button doesn't move. What do I do?

Comment: Can you provide the full code? With the example you provided it works fine.

Comment: I've updated my code. Please have a look.

Comment: This is the only part where I am having problem, the rest are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have the left: 39em; top:31.5em; as inline style. You can override these to reposition the button as follows:

```css
#save{
     border-radius: 12px;
     padding-left: 20px;
     padding-right: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 20px;
     position: absolute; 
     left: 39em; 
     top: 31.5em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    #save{
      left: 19em;
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-left` inside your `<button>` tag

```
<button id="save" style="font-size: 20px; position: absolute; margin-left: 9em; margin-top:31.5em;">Save</button>
```

or in your css code (#save)

```
#save{
         border-radius: 12px;
         margin-left:-15px;
         padding-left: 20px;
         padding-right: 20px;
         cursor: pointer;
    }
```